# Prevent a widget from getting clicked multiple times in a short span

Tags: java, android, android-widget

I have a button that when clicked, saves a canvas to an image file and then calls another activity.  The problem I am having is that through testing, I've noticed the user can click the button twice in a row before the activity is called, resulting in two files being written.

I also noticed the same problem with spinners in another activity. I click them twice in a row in succession and up pops up 2 list views containing all my spinner items.

I've been trying to Google this without much luck.  Is there a simple fix to this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well as it turns out, I had to implement both suggestions to get this to work.  +1 to each of you.

I used an indeterminate progress dialog, and a boolean value like so:

```
    Button send = (Button) findViewById(R.id.send);
    send.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {         
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (mAllowSave) {
                mAllowSave = false;
                showDialog(SAVING_DIALOG);
                mSaveFileThread = new SaveFileThread(handler);
                mSaveFileThread.start();
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

You can have a simple boolean value like mClickBeingProcessed that you set to true as soon as your method that saves the canvas is called.  If it's true, you don't do anything, otherwise you save the canvas and call the other activity.  At the end of your method (or other processing) set it back to false.

Another option is to store a timestamp for the most recent click.  If the click happens within X time of the previous click (whatever value you decide, maybe 1000ms), it is ignored.

Comment: How did you write the message I wanted to write seven minutes before I saw the question?!  +1  :)

Comment: It's my mutant power for the day.  By the time I got in line, they were all out of the cool ones like controlling time, but seeing 7 minutes into the future seemed okay.

Comment: I considered this, but it seems like a hack rather than a real solution.  Are we supposed to have to implement a boolean value for every widget?  That is ridiculous.

Comment: It depends what the widgets do.  If every instance of the widget has the exact same function, you can use a single boolean for all of them.  If each instance is actually separate, then you might use a Map (widgetID:boolean).

Answer (score 1):

simply show a progress dialog till  your processing is going on
see this.
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html
thanks.