# Button get clicked multiple times by clicking it once

Tags: android, button, onclick

I click a **Button** once, but it seems to be that `onClick()` gets fired multiple times. I tried with `mybutton.setClickable(false);` in `onClick()`, but it doesn't seem to work. Any solutions?

Comment: plese post you current code ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Prevent a widget from getting clicked multiple times in a short span](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4653963/prevent-a-widget-from-getting-clicked-multiple-times-in-a-short-span)

..

```
Button send = (Button) findViewById(R.id.send);
        send.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {         
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (mAllowSave) {
                    mAllowSave = false;
                    //
                }
            }
        });
```

and set mAllowSave to true when you need button active orcan  use send.postDelay to activate that again...

so put these line in onClick as well so your button will be active after 1/2 second than previous click

```
send.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            mAllowSave = true;

        }
    },  500);
```